# Ошибка при установке модуля

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup

Я скачал модуль. Там есть файл `setup.py`. Как я понял для установки надо его запустить, но он выдает ошибку:

```
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 397
normalized_version,
UserWarning: Normalizing '1.2.dev'to '1.2.dev0'
```

Как её исправить? У меня версия питона 3.
Вот сам модуль - https://github.com/SkyBiometry/python-face-client/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Попробуйте так: `python setup.py install`

Comment: сработало, спасибо

Comment: В списке модулей он появился, но при импорте он подчёркнутый и пишет "intellisense may be missing for this module python" это что значит?

Comment: Думаю, это предупреждение о том, что IDE может и не смочь подсказать по модулю -- его классы, методы и т.п. На работу кода это не повлияет

Answer (score 1):

Автору помогла команда в консоли:

```
python setup.py install
```